# sqlite error querying Android

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to recover from my `database` the list of songs downloaded with my program.

```
Cursor c = mDb.query(DB_TABLE_SONGS, null, KEY_SONG_DOWNLOADED+" = true", null, null, null, null);
```

And I receive that error

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: true:
```

**while compiling:**

```
SELECT * FROM songs WHERE downloaded = true
```

Answer (score 1):

Your are missing '' for comparing to a string type column.Try this

```
Cursor c = mDb.query(DB_TABLE_SONGS, null, KEY_SONG_DOWNLOADED+" = 'true'", null, null, null, null);
```